# HTML5/JS - Start several webworkers

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, performance, web-worker

I'm currently writing on a program, where I have to deal with huge arrays. I can however split those arrays. My plan now is, to process the arrays in different web workers. I have however never worked with them and do have several questions:

**1.** How would I run several web workers? I tried a for-loop looking like that:

```
for(i = 0; i < eD.threads; i++){
    //start workers here 
    var worker = new Worker("js/worker/imageValues.js");
    worker.postMessage(brightness, cD.pixels[i]);
}
```

Here I do get the error, that the object couldn't be cloned. Which seems logical. I guess it would be better to save them in an Array?

**2.** How would I control that all have finished their work? (I need to reassembly the array and work with it later)

**3.** How many web workers really bring an improvement?

**4.** Is there any advanced tutorial, besides the MDN-entry?

Thank you!

Comment: For #2: You'd have to use `postMessage` from the Worker to send back a message to this parent JS saying that worker is done processing (and probably pass the results)...so you'd have to add an `onmessage` listener for each Worker, in the loop. You'd store all these responses in probably an array. When the number of responses in the array is the same as the number of workers created, that should mean all are done...and you can deal with that array you created. This could be made "cleaner" by using the concept of jQuery's deferred objects

Comment: "Cannot be cloned" here means that what you're *passing to* the worker couldn't be cloned. To avoid race conditions, objects are never shared between workers and the main thread. Objects must either be copied into the worker's memory space, or (with `Blob`s and typed arrays) the main thread may relinquish memory space to a worker and lose the reference to the object.

Comment: Ok. Read about it, but forgot it. Anyway. If I create a temporary variable in the loop, safe the array as a string and pass that string on, would that be a better solution? Somewhere I read, that I only send Strings to workers, somewhere else it says, that I can transfer variables? Thank you both for your explanation though, helps me to get started!

Comment: @stiller_leser [According to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#safe-passing-of-structured-data), worker's `postMessage` can pass virtually anything except functions and host objects (e.g. DOM nodes). If you try to pass an object or array that contains functions or DOM nodes, the copy will fail.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> 1. How would I run several web workers? I tried a for-loop looking like that:

There's no problem with creating more than one worker, even if you don't keep track of them in an array. See below.

> 2. How would I control that all have finished their work? (I need to reassembly the array and work with it later)

They can post a message back to you when they're done, with the results. Example below.

> 3. How many web workers really bring an improvement?

How long is a piece of string? :-) The answer will depend on the target machine on which this is running, the nature of the code running and what other resources it uses, etc. You'll have to tune for your target environment and task. You can find out how many cores are available using [`navigator.hardwareConcurrency`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/hardwareConcurrency) on browsers and Deno or [`os.cpus`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#oscpus) on Node.js, but remember you're sharing those cores with other processes on the machine, it's not just your JavaScript code that's running.

> 4. Is there any advanced tutorial, besides the MDN-entry?

There isn't a lot "advanced" about web workers. :-) I found [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) was sufficient.

Here's an example running five workers and watching for them to be done:

Main window:

```js
display("Starting workers...");
let running = 0;
for (let n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {
    workers = new Worker("worker.js");
    workers.onmessage = workerDone;
    workers.postMessage({ id: n, count: 10000 });
    ++running;
}
function workerDone(e) {
    --running;
    display("Worker " + e.data.id + " is done, result: " + e.data.sum);
    if (running === 0) {
        // <== There is no race condition here, see below
        display("All workers complete");
    }
}
function display(msg) {
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

`worker.js`:

```js
this.onmessage = (e) => {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let n = 0; n < e.data.count; ++n) {
        sum += n;
    }
    this.postMessage({ id: e.data.id, sum: sum });
};
```

About the race condition that doesn't exist: If you think in terms of true pre-emptive threading, then you might think: I could create a worker, increment `running` to `1`, and then before I create the next worker I could get the message from the first one that it's done, decrement `running` to `0`, and mistakenly think all the workers were done.

That can't happen in the environment web workers work in. Although the environment is welcome to start the worker as soon as it likes, and a worker could well finish before the code starting the workers finished, all that would do is *queue* a call to the `workerDone` function for the main JavaScript thread. There is no pre-empting. And so we know that all workers have been started before the first call to `workerDone` is actually executed. Thus, when `running` is `0`, we know they're all finished.

Final note: In the above, I'm using `onmessage = ...` to hook up event handlers. Naturally that means I can only have one event handler on the object I'm doing that with. If you need to have multiple handlers for the `message` event, use `addEventListener`. All browsers that support web workers support `addEventListener` on them (you don't have to worry about the IE `attachEvent` thing).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm going to work through it. The pieces of String is actually imagaData of a canvas turned into a string. For a resolution of 1300 * 1700px you end up with an array with the length of 8840000. So I figured I split the array into x pieces (depending on a user controllable number of threads). Each part of the whole array is going to be processed. Afterwards the imageData-array is rebuild and drawn onto a canvas. At least according to my plan :D

Comment: @stiller_leser: Sounds like the kind of thing web workers were meant for. :-) But I wasn't actually talking about strings in the computer sense. "How long is a piece of string?" is a British idiom, basically meaning "There are too many variables to answer that."

Comment: :D - I didn't expect an idiom here. Haven't had too many idioms in school, so long: You live and learn.

Comment: Also notably for anyone finding this tread.  Canvas element have special passing semantics now, so serializing to a string is no longer necessary :)

Comment: [This link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-gettingstarted-workercomm) is good overview, the "transferrable objects" section is the part that you are interested in.

Comment: @meawoppl: LOL, I had that link in the answer! I just didn't remember transferrable objects. :-) Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why the Compat Table says Safari did remove `navigator.hardwareConcurrency` but it's here in both current stable 16.3 and TP 16.4. Also, apparently Deno has it out of the box where you'd expect it to be [1](https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/main/cli/tsc/dts/lib.deno.window.d.ts#L98) & [2](https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/main/cli/tsc/dts/lib.deno.worker.d.ts#L62).

Comment: @Kaiido - **Thanks!** LOL, that's what I get for just looking at the docs briefly (I didn't see `navigator`, you see, but even though I know Deno's mission in part is to be web platform compatible, I didn't just *try it*). It may be worth opening a bug for the Safari web info. (I don't use Safari except on my phone, and don't use a Mac.) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

stiller_leser. If you still work on the problem, take a look at the [ng-vkthread](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/ng-vkthread) plugin. It allows you to implement parallel computing technique, which you're trying to develop in your project. With this plugin you can execute multiple functions in multiple threads simultaneously.

Function can be defined directly in the main thread or called from an external javascript file.

Function can be:

- Regular functions
- Object's methods
- Functions with dependencies
- Functions with context
- Anonymous functions

Basic usage:

```
/* function to execute in a thread */
function foo(str) {
    return str.toUpper();
}

function bar(str) {
    return str.toUpper();
}

// to execute these 2 functions in 2 threads: //

/* create objects, which you pass to vkThread as an argument*/
var param1 = {
      fn: foo,
      args: ['hello']
  };
var param2 = {
      fn: bar,
      args: ['world']
  }

/* run thread */
vkThread.execAll([param1,param2]).then(
  function (data) {
    $scope.repos = data[0] + ' ' + data[1]; // <-- HELLO WORLD
  }
);
```

Examples and API doc: http://www.eslinstructor.net/ng-vkthread/demo/

Hope this helps,

--Vadim