# jQuery / Javascript function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 functions func1(), func2() and func3(). They are independent of each other. I would like to execute these 3 methods in parallel and with a single call back method. is it possible something like this

```
function parentMethod(){
 call ([func1(),func2(), func3()],<callback function>);
}
```

Callback functionality is optional but can these 3 functions be executed in parallel.

Comment: Why not just run the functions directly inside of `parentMethod()`? Are they async functions?

Answer (score 3):

Use a promise chain with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
Promise.all([func1, func2, func3]).then(values => {
    //values from all the functions are in the callback param
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm, is it part of ES 6?

Comment: Correct, there are shims out there in case you can't use ES6 yet, or you can transpile, but Promise.all has made my life so much more easier it's better to get with it

Comment: But IE doesn't support Promise. Is there any work around? if no then I shall use babel in that case.

Comment: A [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/114) could solve that for you

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the promise answer given, you'll need to "promisify" your functions if they don't already return promises (this demo assumes an error-first callback):

```
let promises = [func1, func2, func3].map(func => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        func((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        })
    });
});

Promise.all(promises)
    .then((results) => {
        let [func1Data, func2Data, func3Data] = results;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('error!', err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use web workers but it'll be a little more verbose solution. You can check this post: [HTML5/JS - Start several webworkers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191779/html5-js-start-several-webworkers)