# Web Worker loaded inline with worker-loader not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, web-worker

I have the following code:

**src/store/modules/outcome-analyzer/outcome-analyzer.js**

```
import Worker from 'worker-loader!./set-hit-percentages.worker.js';

// ...

let actions = {
  setHitPercentages: function (context) {
    let worker = new Worker();
    // let players = resultsMutations.constructPlayersForSetHitPercentages(context.state);

    // worker.postMessage({
    //   message: 'get hit percentages',
    //   players: players,
    // });

    worker.postMessage({
      message: 'test',
      value: 'foobar',
    });

    worker.onmessage = function (e) {
      if (e.data.message === 'finished') {
        context.commit('outcomeAnalyzer/setHitPercentages', e.data.hitPercentages);
      }
    };
    worker.terminate();
  },
};
```

**src/store/modules/outcome-analyzer/set-hit-percentages.worker.js**

```
self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
  debugger;
  if (e.data.message === 'test') {
    console.log(e.data.value);
  }
  else if (e.data.message === 'get hit percentages') {}
});
```

When `setHitPercentages` is called, it is supposed to post a message to the worker, and the worker is supposed to receive it. The worker never receives it. The `debugger` in `set-hit-percentages.worker.js` never is hit, and neither is the `console.log`.

- Inside the `setHitPercentages` debugger, I see that `Worker` is defined. I also see that `worker` is defined after `let worker = new Worker();` runs. `worker` has `onmessasge` and `onerror` methods, and it inherits other stuff like `postMessage`.
- I have [`worker-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader) in my `node_modules`. In `package.json` I have `"worker-loader": "^1.1.1"`.
- I'm using a worker in another part of my code, and it works. The code that works seems to be exactly analogous to the code I posted here that doesn't work, including the `import Worker from 'worker-loader!./xxx-yyy-zzz.worker.js';` part.
- I'm using Chrome. I also tried Safari, and it didn't work there either.
- When I reproduce the problem, I don't start the other worker, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18192122/1927876) says that multiple workers shouldn't cause problems. (I've also tried starting the other worker, terminating it, and then running the code in question, and the problem still occurs in that scenario as well. And when I comment out the code for the other worker, I also continue to have the problem.)
- It's a Vue app started with [vue-webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack).

Comment: What happens if you substitute in the worker that _does_ work? Does it load then? Also, in the Chrome JS debugger, if you hit a breakpoint in the main thread, you should be able to see the worker processes listed out. It'd be worth checking if the worker was actually spawned.

Comment: Old post, but maybe helpful: https://blog.chromium.org/2012/04/debugging-web-workers-with-chrome.html

Comment: @Jacob I do _not_ see the worker process spawn in the debugger, whereas I _do_ see it spawn in the other code.

Comment: @Jacob Interestingly, when I substitute in the worker that does work, it doesn't work anymore. (The debugger in that worker no longer is hit; and I don't see the worker spawn in the dev tools anymore.)

Comment: Dumb question, but is it just that `worker.terminate()` line at the end that's your problem? It looks like you're killing it immediately.

Comment: @Jacob YES!!!!! Thank you so much!!!! My jaw literally dropped. The `terminate` line should be in the `finished` listener. Where I have it now, it kills the worker after `postMessage` is called and `onmessage` sets up the listener. Sorry for getting overly dramatic here lol. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll mark it best and give you a bounty, thanks so much, it totally slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplaced your `worker.terminate();`, which you probably wanted in your `onmessage` handler. As it is now, the worker is being spawned, but killed almost immediately after.